# Rewrite rule not passing variable

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following code in my functions.php file, and it simply will not work to return the value passed via the URL. This is the code below:

```
    function custom_url_source() {

        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^source/([^/]*)$',
            'index.php?source=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );

        add_rewrite_tag('%source%','([^/]*)');
    }

    add_action('init', 'custom_url_source');


    var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

So by typing 'http://example.com/source/the-times/ into the URL I'm expecting to see 'source' => 'the-times' in the var dump, but I see an empty array.

I have flushed my rewrite rules, and the standard .htaccess is in place. The server is a standard LAMP configuration.

Any indicators would be great. I've tried various solutions outlined on here and had no luck. I've Googled and the examples given don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'source' as an custom query var, rather than defining it as a rewrite tag.

```
function wpse162627_add_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = "source";
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse162627_add_query_vars' );    

function custom_url_source() {

     add_rewrite_rule(
         '^source/([^/]*)$',
         'index.php?source=$matches[1]',
         'top'
     );

}
add_action('init', 'custom_url_source');
```